# Goroutines sharing slices : : trying to understand a data race

Tags: arrays, go, channel, goroutine

I try to make a program in Go to find some genes in very large files of DNA sequences. I already made a Perl program to do that but I would like to take advantage of the goroutines to perform this search in parallel ;)

Because the files are huge, my idea was to read 100 sequences at a time, then send the analysis to a goroutine, and read again 100 sequences etc.

I would like to thank the member of this site for their really helpful explanations concerning slices and goroutines.

I have made the suggested change, to use a copy of the slice processed by the goroutines. But the -race execution still detect one data race at the level of the `copy()` function :

Thank you very much for your comments !

```
    ==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read by goroutine 6:
  runtime.slicecopy()
      /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/slice.go:113 +0x0
  main.main.func1()
      test_chan006.go:71 +0xd8

Previous write by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      test_chan006.go:63 +0x3b7

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      test_chan006.go:73 +0x4c9
==================
[>5HSAA098909 BA098909 ...]
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66

    line 71 is : copy(bufCopy, buf_Seq)
    line 63 is : buf_Seq = append(buf_Seq, line)
    line 73 is :}(genes, buf_Seq)




    package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/mathpl/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre"
    "sync"
)

// function read a list of genes and return a slice of gene names
func read_genes(filename string) []string {
    var genes []string // slice of genes names
    // Open the file.
    f, _ := os.Open(filename)
    // Create a new Scanner for the file.
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    // Loop over all lines in the file and print them.
    for scanner.Scan() {
          line := scanner.Text()
        genes = append(genes, line)
    }
    return genes
}

// function find the sequences with a gene matching gene[] slice
func search_gene2( genes []string, seqs []string) ([]string) {
  var res []string

  for r := 0 ; r <= len(seqs) - 1; r++ {
    for i := 0 ; i <= len(genes) - 1; i++ {

      match := pcre.MustCompile(genes[i], 0).MatcherString(seqs[r], 0)

      if (match.Matches() == true) {
          res = append( res, seqs[r])           // is the gene matches the gene name is append to res
          break
      }
    }
  }

  return res
}
//###########################################

func main() {
    var slice []string
    var buf_Seq []string
    read_buff := 100    // the number of sequences analysed by one goroutine

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    queue := make(chan []string, 100)

    filename := "fasta/sequences.tsv"
    f, _ := os.Open(filename)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    n := 0
    genes := read_genes("lists/genes.csv")

    for scanner.Scan() {
            line := scanner.Text()
            n += 1
            buf_Seq = append(buf_Seq, line) // store the sequences into buf_Seq
            if n == read_buff {   // when the read buffer contains 100 sequences one goroutine analyses them

          wg.Add(1)

          go func(genes, buf_Seq []string) {
            defer wg.Done()
                        bufCopy := make([]string, len(buf_Seq))
                        copy(bufCopy, buf_Seq)
            queue <- search_gene2( genes, bufCopy)
            }(genes, buf_Seq)
                        buf_Seq = buf_Seq[:0]   // reset buf_Seq
              n = 0 // reset the sequences counter

        }
    }
    go func() {
            wg.Wait()
            close(queue)
        }()

        for t := range queue {
            slice = append(slice, t...)
        }

        fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

Comment: This doc might be useful to you: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments: Also, that pcre package looks suspect -- it doesn't follow the standards used for package layout, and is quite old, so I wouldn't be surprised if there aren't other issues with it as well.

Comment: Thank you Jim ! I used pcre instead of standard regex because according to my own benchmark, it is much more faster to find if a string is part of another one.

Comment: faster than `strings.Contains` for a simple substring match? (also, it's fine if it works, just giving you a warning that it has some indications it may not be a quality package)

Comment: I tested MatchString() from regexp, glob and pcre. glob was interesting but I did not manage to include a variable pattern in the search, MatchString() was much slower than pcre. I have to test strings.Contains to see if it is fast and powerful enough ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data race exists because slices are reference types in Go. They are generally passed by value, but being reference types, any changes made to the one value is reflected in another. Consider:

```
func f(xs []string) {
    xs[0] = "changed_in_f"
}

func main() {
    xs := []string{"set_in_ main", "asd"}
    fmt.Println("Before call:", xs)
    f(xs)
    fmt.Println("After call:", xs)

    var ys []string
    ys = xs
    ys[0] = "changed_through_ys"
    fmt.Println("After ys:", xs)

}
```

This prints:

```
Before call: [set_in_main asd]
After call: [changed_in_f asd]
After ys: [changed_through_ys asd]
```

This happens because all three slices share the same underlying array in memory. More details [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices).

This is what might be happening when you pass `buf_Seq` to `search_gene2`. A new slice value is passed to each call, however, each slice value may be referring to the same underlying array, causing potential race condition (call to `append` may change the underlying array of a slice).

To solve the problem, try this in your `main`:

```
bufCopy := make([]string, len(buf_Seq))
// make a copy of buf_Seq in an entirely separate slice
copy(buffCopy, buf_Seq)
go func(genes, buf_Seq []string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        queue <- search_gene2( genes, bufCopy)
    }(genes, buf_Seq)
}
```

Comment: This still has a race between the copy and the append in the main loop.

Comment: The race is fixed by the last modification of abhink ! Thank you very much everybody for your very helpful explanations !

Answer (score 6):

The goroutines are only working on copies of the *slice headers*, the underlying arrays are the same. To make a copy of a slice, you need to use `copy` (or `append` to a different slice).

```
buf_Seq = append(buf_Seq, line)
bufCopy := make([]string, len(buf_Seq))
copy(bufCopy, buf_Seq)
```

You can then safely pass `bufCopy` to the goroutines, or simply use it directly in the closure.

Answer (score 1):

The slices are indeed copies, but slices themselves are *reference types*.  A slice, fundamentally, is a 3-word structure.  It contains a pointer to the start of an underlying array, an integer denoting the current number of elements in the slice, and another integer denoting the capacity of the underlying array.  When you pass a slice into a function, a copy is made of this slice "header" structure, but the header still refers to the same underlying array as the header that was passed in.

This means any changes you make to the slice header itself, like sub-slicing it, appending to it enough to trigger a resize (and thus a reallocation to a new location, with a new start pointer), etc will only be reflected in the slice header inside that function.  Any changes to the underlying data itself, however, will be reflected even in the slice outside the function (unless you triggered a reallocation due by growing the slice past capacity).

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/a2y5eGulXW

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the **idiomatic Go** (for this job):
A code is worth a thousand comments:

```golang
genes = readGenes("lists/genes.csv") // read the gene list
n := runtime.NumCPU()                // the number of goroutines
wg.Add(n + 1)
go scan() // read the "fasta/sequences.tsv"
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    go search()
}
go WaitClose()
slice := []string{}
for t := range queue {
    slice = append(slice, t)
}
fmt.Println(slice)
```

`scan()` reads the "fasta/sequences.tsv" to this channel: `var ch = make(chan string, 100)` concurrently and  `search()` is CPU intensive goroutine so for performance reason the number of goroutines limited to `NumCPU`.

Try this working sample code (simulated and tested):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    //"os"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    //"github.com/mathpl/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre"
)

func main() {
    genes = readGenes("lists/genes.csv") // read the gene list
    n := runtime.NumCPU()                // the number of goroutines
    wg.Add(n + 1)
    go scan() // read the "fasta/sequences.tsv"
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go search()
    }
    go WaitClose()
    slice := []string{}
    for t := range queue {
        slice = append(slice, t)
    }
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var genes []string
var ch = make(chan string, 100)
var queue = make(chan string, 100)

func scan() {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer close(ch)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(strings.Join([]string{"A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "H2", "I2"}, "\n")))
    /*f, err := os.Open("fasta/sequences.tsv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
     scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)*/
    for scanner.Scan() {
        ch <- scanner.Text()
    }
}

func match(pattern, seq string) bool {
    //return pcre.MustCompile(pattern, 0).MatcherString(seq, 0).Matches()
    return pattern[0] == seq[0]
}

func search() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for seq := range ch {
        for _, gene := range genes {
            if match(gene, seq) {
                queue <- seq
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

func WaitClose() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(queue)
}

// function read a list of genes and return a slice of gene names.
func readGenes(filename string) []string {
    return []string{"A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "I1"}
    /*var genes []string // slice of genes names
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        genes = append(genes, line)
    }
    return genes*/
}
```

Output:

```
[A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2 I2]
```

I hope this could help for your real case (comments switched in that code, not tested):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    //"strings"
    "sync"

    "github.com/mathpl/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre"
    //pcre "regexp"
)

func main() {
    genes = readGenes("lists/genes.csv") // read the gene list
    n := runtime.NumCPU()                // the number of goroutines
    wg.Add(n + 1)
    go scan() // read the "fasta/sequences.tsv"
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go search()
    }
    go WaitClose()
    slice := []string{}
    for t := range queue {
        slice = append(slice, t)
    }
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var genes []string
var ch = make(chan string, 100)
var queue = make(chan string, 100)

func scan() {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer close(ch)
    //scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(strings.Join([]string{"A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "H2", "I2"}, "\n")))
    f, err := os.Open("fasta/sequences.tsv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        ch <- scanner.Text()
    }
}

func match(pattern, seq string) bool {
    return pcre.MustCompile(pattern, 0).MatcherString(seq, 0).Matches()
    //return pattern[0] == seq[0]
    //return pcre.MustCompile(pattern).Match([]byte(seq))
}

func search() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for seq := range ch {
        for _, gene := range genes {
            if match(gene, seq) {
                queue <- seq
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

func WaitClose() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(queue)
}

// function read a list of genes and return a slice of gene names.
func readGenes(filename string) []string {
    //return []string{"A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "I1"}
    var genes []string // slice of genes names
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        genes = append(genes, line)
    }
    return genes
}
```

---

problems of your code:
1- in `read_genes(filename string) []string` you should check for errors:

```
f, err := os.Open(filename)
if err!=nil{
    panic(err)
}
```

2- in `read_genes(filename string) []string` Close Opened file:

```
defer f.Close()
```

3- After`filename := "fasta/sequences.tsv"` you should check for errors:

```
f, err := os.Open(filename)
if err!=nil{
    panic(err)
}
```

4-  After`filename := "fasta/sequences.tsv"` Close Opened file:

```
defer f.Close()
```

5- Inside `for scanner.Scan() {` if this file `fasta/sequences.tsv` does not contain multiples of 100 lines `if n == read_buff {` will not succeeds for last slice and you will miss it.

6- How many CPU cores do you have? You should limit the number of goroutines.
7- your main question:
I made a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (still problem 5 exists):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func match(pattern, str string) bool {
    return pattern[0] == str[0]
}
func search_gene2(genes, seqs []string) (res []string) {
    for _, r := range seqs {
        for _, i := range genes {
            if match(i, r) {
                res = append(res, r) // is the gene matches the gene name is append to res
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    read_buff := 2 // the number of sequences analysed by one goroutine
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    queue := make(chan []string, read_buff)
    genes := []string{"A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "I1"}
    sequences := strings.Join([]string{"A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "H2", "I2"}, "\n")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(sequences))
    buf_Seq := make([]string, 0, read_buff)
    for n := 1; scanner.Scan(); n++ {
        line := scanner.Text()
        buf_Seq = append(buf_Seq, line) // store the sequences into buf_Seq
        if n == read_buff {             // when the read buffer contains 100 sequences one goroutine analyses them
            wg.Add(1)
            temp := make([]string, n)
            copy(temp, buf_Seq)
            buf_Seq = buf_Seq[:0] // reset buf_Seq
            n = 0                 // reset the sequences counter
            go func(genes, Seq []string) {
                defer wg.Done()
                fmt.Println(Seq)
                queue <- search_gene2(genes, Seq)
            }(genes, temp)
        }
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(queue)
    }()
    slice := []string{}
    for t := range queue {
        slice = append(slice, t...)
    }
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

output (5: `I2` ?):

```
[A2 B2]
[C2 D2]
[E2 F2]
[G2 H2]
[A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2]
```

here is the solution to your main question (make a new slice and copy all data ):

```golang
temp := make([]string, n)
copy(temp, buf_Seq)
buf_Seq = buf_Seq[:0] // reset buf_Seq
n = 0                 // reset the sequences counter
go func(genes, Seq []string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println(Seq)
    queue <- search_gene2(genes, Seq)
}(genes, temp)
```

cause of this:
    Found 1 data race(s)
    exit status 66

```
    line 71 is : copy(bufCopy, buf_Seq)
    line 63 is : buf_Seq = append(buf_Seq, line)
    line 73 is :}(genes, buf_Seq)
```

As other answers said: you shared same underlying array of slice with all goroutines.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Amd for this huge amount of advices !!!  My GO is far to be idiomatic, this is my 2nd program in GO ;)  I choose  to read and process 100 sequences / goroutines, because it gives me the maximum speed. What is still difficult to me is to optimize the size of the buffer channel (should I set this size  =   GOMAXPROCS ?) and the GOMAXPROCS ( = nb of available cores or not ? it is still unclear when I read documentation).

Comment: @Fred  You should limit the number of goroutines (I'd use `runtime.NumCPU() ` as my first  working sample code). then one buffered channel I used in this sample code, and the size of buffer? ( It depends to your system performance: size of buffer `>= min(` how many line per seconds `scanner.Scan()` reads, how many search per seconds `)`, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Amd ! If I understand well,  is is not a problem to oversize the buffer channel, but if it is too small, the program will not run optimally or even worse some results would be uncomplete.

Comment: @Fred It's OK If you have enough RAM, It is a concurrent safe FIFO, It is better to make it optimal by design, but even no buffered channel works well (may be not optimal), anyway it depends to the use case, there is no general rule, in your case , I'd use the above simulated sample cde.